# Hall Scalar product calculation: $\langle h_3p_6, s_{(5,4)}\rangle$

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials, algebraic-combinatorics

This is a problem from an old qualifying exam I am reviewing:

Calculate: $\langle h_3p_6, s_{(5,4)}\rangle$ where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is the Hall scalar product defined by $\langle s_\lambda, s_\mu\rangle = \delta_{\lambda,\mu}$.

Here $s_\lambda,$ etc.. are the symmetric functions in the notation of, e.g., Sagan's *Symmetric Group*. Can someone provide some insight? The way I've done this for (simpler) problems is to write everything in the basis $s_\lambda$; but I am getting stuck on doing this for $h_3$ specifically. Thanks!

===== Update =====

Here is an (attempted) solution. I got an unexpected non-integral answer so I am very curious what, if anything, went wrong. Per the hint I started by writing

$$h_3 = \frac{1}{3!}\text{det}\begin{pmatrix}p_1 & -1 & 0\\ p_2&p_1&-1\\p_3&p_2&p_1\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{6}\left(p_1^3 + 2p_2p_1 + p_3\right)$$

and hence

$$h_3 p_6 = \frac{1}{6}\left(p_{(6,1,1,1)}+2p_{(6,2,1)}+p_{(6,3)}\right)$$

Then, separately, we write

$$s_{(5,4)} = \sum_{\mu\vdash 9}\frac{1}{z_\mu}\chi^{(5,4)}_\mu p_\mu$$

So that, since $\langle p_\nu,p_\lambda\rangle = z_\lambda\delta_\lambda$ where $\delta_\lambda$ is the Kronecher delta, we have

$$ \langle h_3 p_6, s_{(5,4)}\rangle = \frac{1}{6}\left(\chi^{(5,4)}_{(6,1,1,1)}+2\chi^{(5,4)}_{(6,2,1)}+\chi^{(5,4)}_{(6,3)}\right)$$

which is promising. It remains to use Murnaghan-Nakayama rule to calculate the character values, which I did iteratively with rim-hook removal. To this end, some calculations:

$$\begin{split}
\chi^{(5,4)}_{(6,1,1,1)} &= \chi^{(3)}_{(1,1,1)} = \chi^{(2)}_{(1,1)} = \cdots= -\chi^{(0)}_{(0)} = -1\\
\chi^{(5,4)}_{(6,2,1)} &= \chi^{(3)}_{(2,1)} = \cdots = -1\\
\chi^{(5,4)}_{(6,3)} &= \chi^{(3)}_{(3)} = -\chi^{(0)}_{(0)} = -1
\end{split}
$$

So that, in the end, $\langle h_3 p_6, s_{(5,4)}\rangle = -2/3$. This is *an* answer (Lol!) but I would have expected an integer. Maybe I am naïve.

Comment: How about writing everything in terms of the power sum symmetric functions instead?

Comment: @ArB Thanks for the suggestion- I updated the question with an attempted solution. It feels decent but there may be some issues with the determinant calculation or the character values.

Comment: $h_3 p_6 = s_{\left(3\right)} p_6$ is a case for the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule.